# How can I check a specific occurance more than once?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

I am a beginner coder.  My code supposes that the user will enter a word with '*'(stars) and display "same" if the chars before and after the * are the same. For example, for the input ja'*'aisfun, my output should be "same" because a * is between to identical letters. My code seems to work for most cases such as several stars, however when I try a user input like "ja'*'a'*'isfun", the output is "same" even though it should display "different" because of 'a' and 'i' being different letters. I suppose my code is capable of checking only the first star in this case. How can I fix this problem? (Consider the stars wihout the apostrophes)

```
    String ind = "DIFFERENT";
    for (int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++) {
        if ((s.charAt(i) == '*') && (s.charAt(i-1)) == s.charAt(i+1))
            ind = "SAME";
        }
        System.out.print(ind);
    }
    System.out.print("NO");
```

Comment: What do you want to output when there are no stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix your loop index. It should go from `1` to `s.length() - 1`, otherwise you would get a index out of bounds exception if the last or first char is a `*`.

Secondly, it seems like you want to output "DIFFERENT" if there is at least 1 pair of characters around a `*` that is different. You can do this by `break`ing out of the loop as soon as you find a pair that's different:

```
// be careful of bounds of the indexes    
for (int i = 1; i< s.length() - 1; i++) {
    if ((s.charAt(i) == '*')) {
            if ((s.charAt(i-1)) == s.charAt(i+1)) {
                ind = "SAME";
            } else {
                ind = "DIFFERENT";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(ind);
```

Alternatively, you could use a regex solution:

```
if (Pattern.compile("(.)\\*(?!\\1)").matcher(s).find()) {
    System.out.println("DIFFERENT");
} else {
    System.out.println("SAME");
}
```

Comment: As you said, the first index should begin at 1 in the for loop. In the given code it starts with 0. If the first is *. The answer should be edited.

Anyway, i like you solution with the rexeg style

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah Ah, you're right. Thanks for the edit. I wrote the code before I realised the index should start at 1...

Answer (score 1):

You must limit the loop from the 2nd char up until the 2nd from the end and break when a match is found (I suppose):

```
String ind = "DIFFERENT";
for (int i = 1; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
    if ((s.charAt(i) == '*') && (s.charAt(i-1)) == s.charAt(i+1)) {
        ind = "SAME";
        break;
    }
}
System.out.print(ind);
```

Also drop:

```
System.out.print("NO");
```